# discord.py - 'TypeError: on_member_ban() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' error when on_member_ban event runs

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a logging system. (thank god finally something else for once) Everything has been going smoothly, until now. I have a issue with my on_member_ban event, and it gives me an error saying

> TypeError: on_member_ban() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

I've tried everything, no answer. The thing is, I don't see 2 positional arguments. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this error?

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
        with open("database\\wae.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        if str(message.guild.id) in data:
            isenabled = data[str(message.guild.id)]['logchlID']
            if isenabled == 0:
                return
            else:
                channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(message.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Banned", description=f"", color=discord.Colour.red())
                embed.add_field(name="Banned by", value=f"{message.author}")
                embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"{message.reason}")
                embed.set_author(name=f"{entry.author.display_name} (@{entry.author.name})", icon_url=message.author.avatar)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar)
                await channelrs.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_ban#discord.on_member_ban):

> `discord.on_member_ban(guild, user)`
>  Called when user gets banned from a Guild.
>
> This requires `Intents.moderation` to be enabled.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - **guild** (Guild) – The guild the user got banned from.
> - **user** (Union[User, Member]) – The user that got banned. Can be either User or Member depending if the user was in the guild or not at the time of removal.

According to the docs here it looks like this event will pass along both the guild object of the guild the user was banned from, and the user that was banned from that guild. It looks like you are overriding these event callbacks, so you'll need to stick to the parameters that are passed on the discord.py side.

Here is an example of something you could do instead:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
    async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
        with open("database\\wae.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        if str(guild.id) in data:
            isenabled = data[str(guild.id)]['logchlID']
            if isenabled == 0:
                return
            else: ...
```